# Синтаксис REST API

Tags: api, rest, синтаксис

Каков синтаксис REST API? И с каким языком связано REST?

Answer (score 1):

REST - это Representational State Transfer — "передача состояния представления". REST API не связан с конкретным языком.

Вообще, пуристы считают, что правильно говорить RESTful API и RESTful протокол.

А простыми словами говоря, REST - это способ приделать к программе, котрая что то делает, "ручки" (или рычаги, или кнопки - в общем, органы управления), "подёргать" за котрые можно при помощт HTTP - протокола.

При этом кроме методов GET и POST используется еще ряд методов, таких, напрмер, как DELETE. Имя HTTP-метода связано с выполняемой операцией.

Опять таки, REST - это не отдельный протокол, это расширение протокола HTTP. A REST API - это API, определенный припомощи протокола REST.

Посмотриет пример какого нибудь [todo list REST API](https://blog.kvas.dev//to-do-list-3-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5-web-api/) - по моему, станет понятнее.